# Unable to call API through proxy

Tags: java, api, http, tomcat

I have a java application deployed on my local Tomcat server. This application needs to call some APIs to work properly, but unfortunately, I get different exceptions with different approaches and I don't know how to solve this problem. When I run this code snippet locally it works fine. But after deploying it doesn't work anymore.
The first thing I tried was this:

```
        CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
    try {
        HttpHost target = new HttpHost(apiAdress, 443, "HTTPS");
        HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost(proxyAdress, 80, "HTTP");

        RequestConfig config = RequestConfig.custom()
                .setProxy(proxy)
                .build();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet(getPath);
        request.setConfig(config);

        CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(target, request);
        try {
            LOG.debug("----------------------------------------");
            LOG.debug(response.getStatusLine().toString());

            HttpEntity responseEntity = response.getEntity();
            if(responseEntity!=null) {
                String responseString = EntityUtils.toString(responseEntity);
                return JsonUtils.getObjectFromJson(responseString, NachrichtenResponse.class);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.error(e.getMessage(),e);
        } finally {
            response.close();
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        LOG.error(ex.getMessage(),ex);
    } finally {
        try {
            httpclient.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return null;
```

this leads to the following exception:

```
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:146)
at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:131)
at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280)
at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:382)
... 106 common frames omitted
```

When I change the scheme of the proxy to HTTPS like this

```
HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost("94.100.132.14", 80, "HTTPS");
```

this leads to the following exception:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
```

and without a proxy configured I get the exception connection refused. I don't really know what the problem is and I'm having trouble figuring this out. Has anyone ever face a similar problem and has a solution for this?

Comment: Do you try to Google the exception message?

Comment: Since 80 is http port, tried with `new HttpHost("94.100.132.14", 80, "HTTP")` ?

Comment: When you said 'after deploying', did you mean you deployed in an 'organisational' infrastructure ? Normally, there are lot of firewalls and network configurations for incoming and outgoing traffics.

Answer (score -1):

Dont you have to add the certificate to the truststore ?

Comment: Are you answering or just asking for clarifications? Latter should be posted in comments.

Comment: Please rephrase to avoid the impression of being a clarification question. Turn this into an assertive answer.